# IPad text input types - labels in input

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, textinput

If you look at this [link](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=ipad%20text%20box&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=995&bih=507&tbm=isch&tbnid=F3QIWenNGlDtsM:&imgrefurl=http://www.uwec.edu/Help/email/Apple-Mobile-Devices.htm&docid=3QJ1DqCNFL0dPM&imgurl=http://www.uwec.edu/Help/General/images/Exchangeinfo_2.PNG&w=503&h=340&ei=68roT-eILOGW2QWZ-9yNCw&zoom=1) you will see an ipad type of text boxes.
Notice how the label is actually inside of the button. 
I was wondering if there is something similar in JQuery Mobile as I have not seen how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for but you could use Placeholders: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery mobile list view;

check following link

```
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-forms-inset.html
```

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [CSS place holders](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css), i.e. `placeholder="Username"`, such as is shown in the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" 
           placeholder="Username"/>
</div>
```

See a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HeBLk/) demo.